# Finding the number of unique positions occupied by every node after sequence of swaps

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, graph, language-agnostic

You have N (N <= 50000) nodes on a line, with node i in position i on the line. You are given a sequence of M different swaps (M <= 20000), that is written in the from (a1, b1) (a2, b2) …. (aM, bM). In every unit of time i = 1…M, the nodes at positions ai and bi swap. Then, the same M swaps happen again in minutes M + 1….2M, and then for 2M + 1…3M, and so on, continuing a cyclic fashion for K units of time (K < 10^18).

So for example,

At unit of time 1, nodes at positions a1 and b1 swap.

At unit of time 2, nodes at positions a2 and b2 swap.

…

At unit of time M, nodes at positions aM and bM swap.

At unit of time M + 1, nodes at positions a1 and b1 swap.

At unit of time M + 2, nodes at positions a2 and b2 swap.

And so on…

For every node, you are asked to determine the number of unique positions that it will occupy.

Example:

6 nodes, M = 4 (sequence consists of 4 swaps), and K = 7 (total units of time is 7).

Sequence:

(1, 2) (2, 3) (3, 4) (4, 5)

Simulation:

Time 0: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Time 1: {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}

Time 2: {2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6}

Time 3: {2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6}

Time 4: {2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6}

Time 5: {3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6}

Time 6: {3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 6}

Time 7: {3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6}

Answer:

Node 1 reaches positions {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, so 5 positions.

Node 2 reaches positions {1, 2, 3, 4}, so 4 positions.

Node 3 reaches positions {1, 2, 3}, so 3 positions.

Node 4 reaches positions {2, 3, 4}, so 3 positions.

Node 5 reaches positions {3, 4, 5}, so 3 positions.

Node 6 doesn’t move, so it reaches position {6}, so 1 position.

One way of solving this could be by treating the nodes as a graph. Then, you could treat each of the swaps as connections, and then use a graph algorithm to calculate how you move between the nodes.

How can I successfully incorporate a graph algorithm into this problem?

EDIT: I’ve spent a few more hours thinking about this problem, and wanted to incorporate Ehsan’s idea into the solution. To find the possible nodes that will be in each position, you can use a recursive function like the one Ehsan is proposing (F(F(...(F(original_order))). Then, you can do this for every step in K. However, this would be an NK solution, which my be too slow as the largest number of operations I can perform is 10^9. How can I optimize my current idea?

Comment: The original didn’t have my approach to solving it, and was closed because it was too vague.

Comment: What you've described as your current "approach" doesn't seem to offer any more substance than you offered here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862705/number-of-distinct-positions-occupied-by-each-node-when-undergoing-sequence-of-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862705/number-of-distinct-positions-occupied-by-each-node-when-undergoing-sequence-of-s). Please show some effort. Voting to close.

Comment: Understood. I added another idea to my post that’s more developed.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need graph for this.
They key point is reducing k

Lemma: assume from original node list `{n1,n2,n3,...,nN}` after series of step `{s1,s2,.....,st}` you reach to new order of nodes like `{n_i1,...,n_iN}` and also you have a unique visited list for each node as `{n1_v1,...,n1_vn1},...,{nN_v1,...,nN_vnN}`

then if you perform the same series of steps again, you can find the new order list of nodes and also unique visited list in `O(n)` with help of previous step.
so it's kind of dynamic programing.
by this approach the complexity of your algorithm could be as `O(n*log(k/m)+m)`

Comment: Can you explain it any better?

Comment: for series of step `{s1,...,st}`  consider a function who transforms `{n1,...,nN}` to {n_i1,...,n_iN}` , so if we do the steps again we can achieve the final series in `O(n)` .for example if the original series is `{1,2,3}` and it became `{3,1,2}` then if we do the steps again it definitely goes to `{2,3,1}`. in other word there's a function `F` which is rotating the indexes in same way every time, just the input order changes over time. it's like `F(F(...(F(original_order)))`

Comment: Can you run through the algorithm in your post with the sample case? I think I would understand it more clearly then.

Comment: @EhsanGerayli so how is that solving the problem?

Comment: Please explain your assessment of time complexity. I don't see how we can get a log factor on K.